# Google Cloud WordPress click to deploy fails to deploy - Waiter time out

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

I am having trouble setting up a WordPress from the GCP marketplace. Following the 15 min tutorial, when I click deploy, it times out with the error message:

[image]

[image]

After some research I found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/gce-discussion/c/Nr45fqKdGU4) where it is suggested to enable the VPC private access to solve the issue. It did not work. So I tried creating a new VPC with only one subnet configured as suggested. Same error.

I've tried other options in the marketplace, and any of them using the Waiter time out. That tells me it's probably something I am missing in my configuration, but I can't see what could be.

Can anyone see anything I am missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried deploying the Wordpress instance in other regions? If so, are you seeing the same error message?

Comment: Yes I have, and it's always the same error message :/